# How order by result based on mod condition?

Tags: sqlite

I want to order my output based on the condition.

```
| Id |    Date  |
-----------------
| 1  | Jan 2020 |
-----------------
| 2  | Feb 2020 |
-----------------
| 3 | Mar 2020 |
-----------------
| 4 | Apr 2020 |
-----------------
| 5 | May 2020 |
-----------------
| 6  | Jun 2019 |
-----------------
| 7  | Jul 2019 |
-----------------
| 8  | Aug 2019 |
-----------------
| 9  | Sep 2019 |
-----------------
| 10  | Oct 2019 |
-----------------
| 11  | Nov 2019 |
-----------------
| 12  | Dec 2019 |
-----------------
```

Data available from the user is just Id, I'm not getting any other information from the user, And based on Id I need to order the records.

So Let say Available Id at my end is 6, Expected output will be like

```
-----------------
| Id |    Date  |
-----------------
| 6  | Jun 2019 |
-----------------
| 7  | Jul 2019 |
-----------------
| 8  | Aug 2019 |
-----------------
| 9  | Sep 2019 |
-----------------
| 10  | Oct 2019 |
-----------------
| 11  | Nov 2019 |
-----------------
| 12  | Dec 2019 |
-----------------
| 1  | Jan 2020 |
-----------------
| 2  | Feb 2020 |
-----------------
| 3 | Mar 2020 |
-----------------
| 4 | Apr 2020 |
-----------------
| 5 | May 2020 |
-----------------
```

Tl;dr;
I want to order the details from id, and loop back the remaining entries, i.e. value less than id.

so far I was able to access the records based on Id, But not able to access the remaining records.

`select * from TableName where Id < @id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by doing conditional ordering:

```
select * from tablename 
order by (Id >= 6) desc, Id
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3Jgc6XTog7en4vCVGwx519/0).
or:

```
select * from tablename 
order by 
  case when Id >= 6 then 0 else 1 end,
  Id
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3Jgc6XTog7en4vCVGwx519/1).
Results:

```
| Id  | Date     |
| --- | -------- |
| 6   | Jun 2019 |
| 7   | Jul 2019 |
| 8   | Aug 2019 |
| 9   | Sep 2019 |
| 10  | Oct 2019 |
| 11  | Nov 2019 |
| 12  | Dec 2019 |
| 1   | Jan 2020 |
| 2   | Feb 2020 |
| 3   | Mar 2020 |
| 4   | Apr 2020 |
| 5   | May 2020 |
```

Comment: That's perfect, Thank you very much.